# ImageMagick and alpha channel CMD

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to create the image with Alpha channel from the second image. I have used this cmd command on windows:

```
magick composite Background.tif  Alpha.tif -compose multiply -alpha on Result.tif
```

This command creates combined tif, but alpha channel is empty.

Would you be able to provide me with any help?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Inputs:

Background.tif
[image]

Foreground.tif
[image]

Output:

Result - Background+ForegroundAlpha100.tif
[image]

Edit:
I have a two commands which do I can. Is possible merge this commands into one command?
First create some inputs:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc:black 100.png 
magick logo: logo.png
```

And this are the two commands I need merge:

```
magick convert 100.png -alpha on -channel A -evaluate set 50% +channel tmp1.png 
magick logo.png tmp1.png -compose copy-alpha -composite alpha50.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sample alpha channel:

```
magick -size 180x80 gradient: -bordercolor white -border 10 alpha.png
```

[image]

Make a sample background of solid red:

```
magick -size 200x100 xc:red background.png
```

[image]

Add alpha channel to solid red background:

```
magick background.png alpha.png -compose copy-alpha -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer but I dont understand. I have a two images. Background.tif + Foreground.tif. I need create (merge compose) one result.tif. Something as layers. So Background.tif + (Foreground:alfachannel.tif) = result.tif

Comment: `magick BACKGROUND FOREGROUND -compose copy-alpha -composite result.png`

Comment: I have tried to simplify and improve the answer. If it still doesn't work, please share a link to your TIFF files via Dropbox or Google Drive or similar - and, if possible, the expected result.

Comment: Yeeeees, it looks good. God bless you and thank you very much :)

Comment: Is possible reduce density in this alpha channel please? For example to 50%?

Comment: @user8915316 You can change it inside parentheses so it doesn't affect the background, like this `magick BACKGROUND \( ALPHA -evaluate multiply 0.5 \) -compose ...` or you can load the alpha and modify it, then load the background afterwards (so it isn't affected by the multiply) and then swap the order like this `magick ALPHA -evaluate multiply 0.5 BACKGROUND +swap ...`

Comment: Thank you Mark. It works fine. But I don't really understand which value is multiplying. I have a gray tif and I would like convert Black color (100%K) into 50%K or 30%K. White canvas do not touch. Im trying some other evaulate operators, but result is not good.

Comment: If you click `edit` under your question and add input and output images, I may be able to help you better.

Comment: I did it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I really can't understand what you are trying to do. Your black text shows up as white when you overlay the two images, but shows up as black in your coverage diagram, and sometimes you call it an alpha layer implying it makes something transparent or has transparency but it has none and sometimes you call it a foreground layer.  Sorry, I am confused.

Comment: Im sorry, my English is not ideal and thank you very much for your efforts. I will try to describe it like this:
Sometimes the Alpha (mask) must have 100% transparency and sometimes only 50% transparency.